# Share Intent, inconsistent behaviour

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, share

I am not sure how to ask this question. This is not completely a problem, but is seen on some specific scenarios, let me put this like:

I have developed an app, that exposes 2 share intent, one is for Sharing and the other is for Viewing.

The sharing intent, shares a file with custom extension. When I use k9 mail app to share the app, it appears in the attachment, but using the default android mail app does not show the file in the attachment.

The view intent on the other hand, appears in the share list when I use ES File Explorer, but does not appear when I use File Expert file explorer.

I have used `mimeType="application/myCustomExtension"` in the android manifest for the view intent. Changing it to `mimeType="*/*"` and `android:pathPattern=".*\\.CUSTOM_FILE_EXTENSION"` along with `android:host` and `android:scheme` makes it appear in the share list, but for all other files as well, not only for my custom extension.

While this is not exactly a problem because my code works for some file managers and email clients and doesn't work in some. But, I'd like to know if there is some way I can make them consistent through out all apps.

Moreover, the bluetooth option also doesn't show up in my share intent when I share my custom extension. I have bluetooth permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

set in manifest.

Please help me in this matter.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out the following things about intent.

1. Intents are resolved at runtime something like this.for eg: if you specify an ACTION_SEND , then all the applications whether system or user generated apps have the action specified as ACTION_SEND in their manifest , they will show up in that intent.

so for actionSend - with the mime set to plain/text ---opens up gmail and default mail in your phone

for mime---- text/html --opens up many options including whatsapp , facebook , bluetooth

so after these apps show to let you share the content its up to the apps to be able to parse the data you attached.
You don't have control over it.

Comment: what if the action is ACTION_SEND & ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE and the mimeType is `*/*` should not bluetooth application show up? besides that, the default mail app shows, but the file with custom extension does not attach, a pdf or doc works well though